# How to find the next element of parent siblings with same class

Tags: jquery

Trying to make specific siblings of a parent item fade in or out.

```
<header class="myheader">
   <h1 class="title">Title 1</h1>
</header>
<ul class="my-list">
   <li>list item 1</li>
</ul>
<header class="myheader">
   <h1 class="title">Title 2</h1>
</header>
<p>description</p>
<ul class="my-list">
   <li>list item 1</li>
   <li>list item 2</li>
   <li>list item 3</li>
</ul>
<header class="myheader">
   <h1 class="title">Title 3</h1>
</header>
<ul class="my-list">
   <li>list item 1</li>
   <li>list item 2</li>
   <li>list item 3</li>
</ul>
```

So, using the mark up above, I want to be able to click any heading **h1** tag and make the next **ul** block visible (fade in).

Using this jQuery I can hide all the **ul** blocks (done in jquery so if js is off all content is still visible), then wait for a click event on a heading **h1** tag with a class of 'myheading' and make the closest next sibling **ul** block fade in.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.title').each(function() {
      $('ul.my-list').hide();

      $(this).click(function() {
         $(this).parent().next('ul.my-list').fadeToggle();
         return false;
      });
   });
});
```

However, this fails for the second heading because it has a paragraph tag before the **ul** block.

How can I target the correct **ul** tag for each heading **h1**? Seeing as jQuery .next() only finds the direct neighbour element, it doesnt search for the nearest next element with the search arguments specified eg 'ul' or a class.

I've tried various versions of .find(), .next(), .nextAll() etc without success. I dont want to add ids to the tags as that defeats the point of using this().

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nextAll('ul.my-list:first')`

`next` limits to the first adjacent item only.

`nextAll` returns all the subsequent items, that can then be filtered to return the first.

You can also do it as `nextAll('ul.my-list').first()` if you prefer (supposed to be slightly faster)

### JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/8ddnV/

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks. I'd forgotten about :first. I actually used your second version with .first() and it works well.